# Drupal 7: Form for node maintenance

Tags: drupal-7

I have a content type which will contain just one node.
I need a form for the maintenance of this node, with the following logic:
If the node exists, show a form populated with the fields content, and a "update" buttom;
If not exists, show a clear form with a "insert" buttom.
What is the Drupal correct way to do this?
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

if the content type will contain one node why will drupal need to check weather the node exists?

Drupal rules http://drupal.org/project/rules coupled with the core triggers and actions modules can help you setup up system logic events